# Passing an unknown Enum to a function

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a list out of an unknown Enum passed as a parameter, but I'm not familiar with the details involved. I extracted the part of my code which I'm working on (there are errors in there, but you'll get the idea):

```
Public Shared Function EnumInListOut(someEnum As System.Enum) As List(Of ComboBoxItem)
    Dim list As New List(Of ComboBoxItem)

    For Each enumItem As Integer In System.Enum.GetValues(TypeOf someEnum)
        list.Add(New ComboBoxItem(System.Enum.GetName(someEnum.GetType, enumItem), enumItem))
    Next

    Return list
End Function
```

The idea is that I want this function to give back names and values of the enum's items as a list, but I can't figure out how to do it. I can change the parameters or, well, anything, as long as I keep in mind that I have no idea exactly which enum I'll get.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this help you further? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=netcore-3.1 Is there any way you can describe better what problem you are having? It seems this question doesn't really have a question in it?

Comment: @Icepickle I'm working with Enums in a context where I'm at a loss at how to manipulate them to do what I described (receive an enum type and spit back info accordingly). I could describe my issues as "I'm failing at enum manipulation", but I doubt it narrows it. I did research the issue enough to get the feeling that there must be some kind of detail which eludes me, maybe a type thing, yet I don't know what. So far.

Comment: So you have compile errors? LIke maybe the `TypeOf someEnum`? You could simply pass in the argument as an `Object`, then use the `Enum.GetNames` and `Enum.Parse` to get the value per name.

Comment: Also, which value do you plan to send in? An enum type or a value?

Comment: @Icepickle Enum type. If I'm stuck I can change tactic and send the enum's content I guess, but I would prefer to avoid this kind of mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you need to get the names and value of a enum type, then you can go ahead like the following

```
Public Function EnumInListOut(enumType As Type) As IDictionary(Of String, Object)
    return [Enum].GetNames( enumType ).ToDictionary( Function(name) name, Function(name) [Enum].Parse( enumType, name ))
End Function
```

Which gives you back a dictionary with names and values to match with the enum type

if you would send in a value of an enum type, you could do it a bit more indirect, like so

```
Public Function EnumInListOut(Of T)(someEnum As T) As IDictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim enumType as Type = GetType(T)
    return [Enum].GetNames( enumType ).ToDictionary( Function(name) name, Function(name) [Enum].Parse( enumType, name ))
End Function
```